# KVM Dynamic Rate Limiting

Tags: ubuntu, networking, kvm-virtualization, openstack

How can I dynamically rate limit the network speed on individual KVM instances? For example, I want to set a rule where if a user uses over 100mbps inbound or outbound bandwidth for over 30 minutes, the instance is throttled to 10mbps.

I am using KVM, Openstack, on an Ubuntu 12 host OS.

Answer (score 3):

As you are using Openstack, when you create a flavour you can specify the rxtx_factor.  My understanding is that this is used to calculate a percentage of the rtx_cap on the network that is available to the VM.
I'm not sure if all hypervisors will support it however, though so you may need to do some additional digging to see if KVM does.